# Calculating the min and max height of B+ tree

Tags: algorithm, b-tree

I was reading about how to calculate the height of a B+ tree, I found the we can calculate it using:
[image]

Where N is the number of keys, and m is the order size. However, I dont know what is meant by the number of keys? Is it the total number of records? Also, how to calculate the order size if I only have the data blocks, number of records, size of each record and the index?

Answer (score 0):

Number of keys is, maximum values that a particular block accepts. You know B+ tree will have key and pointers in a block(consider). If the new value enters, and if the size exceeds, then the split occurs because of overflow.